# Compare $Variables Results, and then orden in different Ways

Tags: php, sql, sorting

Hello i just finish a code where i get like 50 variables... all of them with int values..

I have the variables as separete values, just for this example I will set the variables with the result, BUT the result came from other evaluations and stuff that its fine, cause im already echoing a verified result.

```
$one = 13
$two = 35
$three = 46


The "item1" appears <?PHP echo $one; ?> times<br />
The "item2" appears <?PHP echo $two; ?> times<br />
The "item3" appears <?PHP echo $three; ?> times<br />
```

This is fine but,, How can i order the results, in ASC way or DSC , to build a order by...

Thanks so much

This far this is working great

```
$naturales = array(
  $uno => "n1",
  $dos => "n2",
  $tres => "n3",
  $cuatro => "n4",
  $cinco => "n5",
  $seis => "n6",
  $siete => "n7",
  $ocho => "n8",
  $nueve => "n9",
  $diez => "n10",
  $once => "n11",
  $doce => "n12",
  $trece => "n13",
  $catorce => "n14",
  $quince => "n15",
  $dieciseis => "n16",
  $diecisiete => "n17",
  $dieciocho => "n18",
  $diecinueve => "n19",
  $veinte => "n20",
  $veintiuno => "n21",
  $veintidos => "n22",
  $veintitres => "n23",
  $veinticuatro => "n24",
  $veinticinco => "n25",
  $veintiseis => "n26",
  $veintisiete => "n27",
  $veintiocho => "n28",
  $veintinueve => "n29",
  $treinta => "n30",
  $treintayuno => "n31",
  $treintaydos => "n32",
  $treintaytres => "n33",
  $treintaycuatro => "n34",
  $treintaycinco => "n35",
  $treintayseis  => "n36",
  $treintaysiete => "n37",
  $treintayocho => "n38",
  $treintaynueve => "n39",
  $cuarenta => "n40",
  $cuarentayuno => "n41",
  $cuarentaydos => "n42",
  $cuarentaytres => "n43",
  $cuarentaycuatro => "n44",
  $cuarentaycinco => "n45",
  $cuarentayseis => "n46",
  $cuarentaysiete => "n47",
  $cuarentayocho => "n48",
  $cuarentaynueve => "n49",
  $cincuenta => "n50",
  $cincuentayuno => "n51",
  $cincuentaydos => "n52",
  $cincuentaytres => "n53",
  $cincuentaycuatro => "n54",
  $cincuentaycinco => "n55",
  $cincuentayseis => "n56", 
);

krsort($naturales);

foreach ($naturales as $count => $name) {
  echo "The \"$name\" appears $count times<br />";
}
```

Why my results are like this (Its hidding all the results with 12 (Similar count results)
for example for "n3" appears 12 times. and its not listed.

```
The "n20" appears 12 times
The "n30" appears 11 times
The "n37" appears 10 times
The "n41" appears 9 times
The "n42" appears 8 times
The "n45" appears 7 times
The "n47" appears 6 times
The "n35" appears 5 times
The "n44" appears 4 times
The "n46" appears 2 times
The "n56" appears 0 times
```

Comment: Are you able to insert your values into an array? If so, you can use the [built-in array sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/array.sorting.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$one = 13;
$two = 35;
$three = 46;

$arr = array("Item 1"=>$one,"Item 2"=>$two,"Item 3"=>$three);

echo "<strong>Original</strong><br />";
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br />";
}

asort($arr);
echo "<strong>Ascending Sort</strong><br />";
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br />";
}

arsort($arr);
echo "<strong>Descending Sort</strong><br />";
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br />";
}
```

As previously mentioned, you can use `asort` and `arsort` to sort your array as needed... I'm adding some examples here as well as some working **[CODE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mJnC3d)**

Comment: @JulesMartinez you can play with it if you go to that codepad link I left.

Comment: Thanks but why its always hidding the "similar" count results, for example se my edit, but also happends with your code, "n3" appears 12 times also, and its not listed.. not even with your code..

Comment: @JulesMartinez I'm not really sure what you mean... As you can see in **[this link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kSkNKG)**, nothing is removed when repeated. If you can clarify a bit I can help some more.

Comment: My array is build the opposite way , i do $two => "Item2", you do "Item 2"=>$two

Comment: @JulesMartinez that's fine... You can just use `ksort` or `krsort` if you'd rather sort by key or use `array_flip()` and use my method... [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 3):

Build an array

`$myresults = array("Item1"=>13,"item2"=>35,"item3"=>46);`

then use `asort()` or `arsort()` on the array $myresults

then do a for/foreach loop to output the results

basic guidelines but off this you should be able to google how to implement in detail fairly easily (even on here will work)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you could insert your values into an associative array, i.e.:

```
$items = array(
  $one => "item1",
  $two => "item2",
  $three => "item3"
);
```

and then you can use a function like ksort() to sort all of your values:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

so you can end up with something like this:

```
ksort($items);

foreach ($items as $count => $name) {
  echo "The \"$name\" appears $count times<br />";
}
```